# What are some words that I can use to describe a persons voice?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

One of my characters has a very... interesting voice? It is like a weird mixture of Robin Williams and Jeff Bridges. What words could I use to describe that kind of voice?

Answer (score 1):

"Gruff" immediately comes to mind.

> (of a voice) rough and low in pitch.